# Bug in jQuery DOM element builder for Images with width/height?

Tags: jquery

The [jQuery 1.4 docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) describe how jQuery can be used to create DOM elements on the fly from a provided HTML string and set of attributes.  For example:

```
var d = $('<div/>', {id:'foo', className:'bar'});
d; // => [<div id="foo" class="bar"></div>]
d.attr('id'); // => "foo"
d.attr('class'); // => "bar"
```

This is great; however, there appears to be a bug when using this shortcut for images with width and height.  Instead of setting the attributes (as implied by the [attr() function](http://api.jquery.com/attr)) it sets the CSS style:

```
var x = $('<img/>', {width:10, height:20});
x; // => [<img style=​"width:​ 10px;​ height:​ 20px;​ ">​]!!!
x.attr('width'); // => 0!!!
x.attr('height'); // => 0!!!
```

This is even more confusing since jQuery behaves as expected when given a new image from the constructor:

```
var y = $(new Image(10, 20));
y; // => [<img width=​"10" height=​"20">]
y.attr('width'); // => 10
y.attr('height'); // => 20
```

Is this just a bug in jQuery 1.4.2 or expected behavior for some reason?

Comment: Off topic, but be aware that `class:'bar'` will break in some browsers. You should do `'class':'bar'` or `className:'bar'`.

Comment: @patrick dw: thanks, I'll edit my answer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2)

> As of jQuery **1.4**, the second argument can accept a map consisting of a ***superset*** of the properties that can be passed to the **`.attr()`** method. Furthermore, any event type can be passed in, and the following jQuery methods can be called: *val, css, html, text, data, **width**, **height**, or offset.*

So, these properties get handled by their respective methods, and [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width2) and [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/#height2) apply their values in the style attribute.

---

**Followup from comments below:**

At the very least it is a documentation bug that jQuery doesn't acknowledge the conflict between the legitimate `height` and `width` properties, and the jQuery methods of the same name.

More appropriately it's an API bug that needs to be addressed. A bug report [has been filed here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9323).

Note that this only affects the optional `props` argument when creating elements. The `.attr()` method works correctly with respect to `width` and `height`.

---

**Update:** jQuery has acknowledged the conflict but won't provide any fix suitable to allow its users to apply `width` and `height` in the `props` argument when creating elements.

As such, those properties are unsupported for assignment in that manner. You'll need to apply those properties apart from the rest in a separate function call to `.attr()`, which does correctly support them.

```
var x = $('<img/>', { src:'some/path/to.jpg',
                      alt:'some text' }).attr({ width:100,
                                                height:100 });
```

Comment: +1 They should add `attr` as one of the methods so you could do `{attr:{width:10, height:20}}` to get around such issues.

Comment: @Gaby: Perhaps I will. Do you happen to know off hand if those properties have been deprecated in the spec?

Comment: @patrick, was just checking on that.. it seems that they are not (although they only apply to `img` and `object` i believe..)

Comment: **Specs:** [`img` for html 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.2) and [`img` for xhtml 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/dtd_module_defs.html#a_module_Image)

Comment: So just to be clear, it seems like my confusion is that the "attr()" function handles arguments 'width' and 'height' according to the *functions* "width()" and "height()", which pertain to *style* and **not** *attributes*, as the name of the "attr()" method would imply, right?

Comment: @maerics Yes. It seems a bit unfortunate, as there is a collision of names and they opted for the function versions. Is there a reason you need it to go to the attribute and not the css ? or just wondering for the inconsistency ?

Comment: @Gaby: just wondering about the inconsistency since I hadn't noticed the width/height functions yet, thanks for the insight.  @patrick: thanks for the bug ticket!

Comment: @maerics: You're welcome. @Gaby: Thanks for the links. Added those, and one for HTML5.

Comment: @maerics: Actually, the `.attr()` function works properly with respect to `width` and `height`. It's just the optional `props` argument for creating new elements that is behaving poorly. This will work: `$('<img/>').attr({width:10, height:20});`

Comment: @patrick: it seems like the answer is that the API is a bit confusing due to the special case of the Image width/height attributes as evidenced by the comment conversation; if you post an answer summarizing I'll accept it...

Comment: Gaby: Thanks. :o) @maerics: I've added some of the info from these comments to this answer. You can go ahead and accept this one. :o)

Comment: @patrick, thanks too. For both improving on my answer, and for getting back on the progress of the ticket.

Comment: @Gaby: You're welcome. Made more sense to me to consolidate the info since it was just an extension of the your answer.