# Best practice for using DOM Level 0 in modern JavaScript applications

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is there an agreed set of "best practices" for use of the [DOM Level 0 collections](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/dom0.html) in modern JavaScript applications? (`document.forms`, `document.images`, etc.)

In applications using jQuery, I've noticed a tendency to, say, change the contents of a drop-down using `$(...).html()` to switch out the underlying nodes, rather than using [`element.options[]`](http://ln.hixie.ch/?start=1161042744&order=-1&count=1). Is this because the DOM 0 collections are best avoided, or because jQuery makes it much easier to change the underlying DOM structure?

**Edit:** I guess part of the question includes if the older features are reliable cross-browser. I remember that, once upon a time, IE would add `<tbody>` tags automatically to your table, while firefox would not. That made walking the dom tree painful cross-browser. Similarly, `element.options[]` had [problems when changing the options in the collection](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t20). Are these guys reliable cross-browser?

Comment: +1 very good question. I've always avoided em just because I don't trust browsers' native code to fill and respond to modifications of those collections all the same way.

Comment: Some of the problems may have arisen from quirks mode, come to think of it...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First off, great question.

DOM Level 0-1 functionality is my favorite toolbox to work with. The support is tremendous. I'll highlight the pros and cons for each subset of DOM Level 0 below:

### DOM Level 0 Events

Since these are added as properties of an *ElementNode*, you can only have one handler. For some instances (eg: event delegation), this is burdensome. However, I feel that the DOM is diverse enough (especially as your project gets bigger) to have enough room for DOM level 0 handlers. DOM Level 2 listeners are painful to implement without a library/framework to smooth over older browsers. Even as a Flash developer (listeners are used everywhere), the DOM 0 events are far easier to me. One of the highlights is the fact that the `this` value is set for you (without IE hacking and coughing like the other model). For example, consider this markup:

`<div id="foo">Cick Me!</div>`

Now, all that needs to be done is selection and attachment of a DOM Level 0 handler.

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
function bar()
{
    console.log(this); //<div id="foo">
}
foo.onclick = bar;
```

That's a very easy way of selecting elements and an alternative to [Event.currentTarget](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-interface-h2);

There's a great discussion on DOM Level 0 events vs. DOM Level 2 events here: [[link](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/browse_thread/thread/33e4472d2fe16e53/b9d491ab8cf1cbca?lnk=gst&q=DOM%20Level%200)]

---

### DOM Level 0 HTMLCollections

Bar none, *HTMLCollections* are my favorite feature of the DOM. Because nodes are selected for you, there's no need to run queries. In my opinion, they're the most overlooked DOM feature today. Name traversal such as: `collection["name"]` is very handy and certainly helps when traversing forms. For example, consider this bit of markup:

```
<form action="./" id="foo" name="foo" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Dummy Form</legend>
        <input type="text" name="bar">
        <select name="baz">
            <option selected value="1">1</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

There are many DOM Level 0 ways to tackle this.

1. `var foo = document.forms.foo; //<form id="foo" onsubmit="return false;" method="post" name="foo" action="./">`

   Demo: http://jsbin.com/udozoz/0edit#preview
2. `var foo = document.forms[0]; //<form id="foo" onsubmit="return false;" method="post" name="foo" action="./">`

   Demo: http://jsbin.com/udozoz/2/edit#preview
3. `var foo = document.getElementById("foo"); //<form id="foo" onsubmit="return false;" method="post" name="foo" action="./">`

   Demo: http://jsbin.com/udozoz/3/edit#preview

Certainly, method 3 is more preferable. It's DOM Level 1, and not DOM Level 0. However, name traversal fits naturally for the [HTMLFormElement.elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-76728479) *HTMLCollection*. Since you're supposed to use `name` attributes on form elements, you can easily access them without an `id` attribute.

Ex: `var baz = foo.elements.baz;`

When using radio buttons that share the same name (to make only one selectable at a time), you can use the [HTMLFormElement.elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-76728479) *HTMLCollection* to select all of the radio buttons. That's very powerful. Consider this markup:

```
<form action="./" id="foo" name="foo" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Radio Buttons</legend>
        <label for="select_1">1</label>
        <input id="select_1" type="radio" name="selectable" value="a">
        <label for="select_2">2</label>
        <input id="select_2" type="radio" name="selectable" value="b">
        <label for="select_3">3</label>
        <input id="select_3" type="radio" name="selectable" value="c">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

You could use this simple code and have every radio button with the `name` attribute value of "selectable":

1. ```
   var foo = document.forms.foo;
   var selectables = foo.elements.selectable;
   console.log(selectables); //[input#select_1 a, input#select_2 b, input#select_3 c]
   ```

   Demo: http://jsbin.com/upiyom/edit#preview
2. ```
   var foo = document.forms.foo;
   var selectables = foo.selectable;
   console.log(selectables); //[input#select_1 a, input#select_2 b, input#select_3 c]
   ```

   Demo: http://jsbin.com/upiyom/2/edit#preview

Option 2 enables you to bypass the `elements` *HTMLCollection* completely. While certainly not as clear as Option 1, it's still used today.

*HTMLCollections* have become more populous and far more diverse since the introduction of DOM Level 0. For example, take a look at the *HTMLCollections* available for a table. It's staggering. There's [HTMLTableElement.rows](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6156016), [HTMLTableElement.tBodies](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-63206416), [HTMLTableSectionElement (thead, tbody, tfoot).rows](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-52092650), and [HTMLTableRowElement.cells](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-67349879). Those collections are very powerful, and have made DOM traversal far simpler with tables (permitting you use them).

---

### DOM Level 0 Properties

While the properties on *ElementNodes* weren't as diverse in DOM Level 0 as they are now, there's still a couple of gems to note:

[HTMLInputElement.defaultChecked](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-20509171)

`defaultChecked` enables you to bypass searching through an [HTMLInputElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6043025)'s `checked` attribute completely because it stores a boolean based on that attribute's value. This means you don't have to kludge through sloppy solutions for IE builds related to get/set/removeAttribute. Later on, the `defaultValue` property would also be added to fill a similar need.

[document.lastModified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.lastModified) [non-standard]

`lastModified` will store the last time the document was changed. It's a cool little feature that has limited use.

[HTMLDocument.title](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-18446827)

`title` will snag the document's title for you. Its usage is a small niche at best.

---

In regards to your `tbody` question, browsers today do add an [HTMLTableSectionElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-67417573) (tbody) if you don't to promote proper DOM structure. You should get to know proper table markup so this won't be a problem in the future :).

Example markup:

Wrong:

```
<table>
    <!-- tbody will be inserted here and will wrap the tr -->
    <tr>
        <td>Hello, World!</tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Right:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello, World!</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/exomub/edit#preview

---

### Summary

The main point that needs to be driven home is that most of DOM Level 0 is standardized in DOM Levels 1 and 2. This means the browser support is extensive (since it's really old). There shouldn't be too much apprehension to using it—aside from some edge cases in older browser builds. At the end of the day, it's your choice.

I'd like to add that I've only very briefly—in the past—been employed to develop with HTML/JavaScript. I do it as a hobby, so I'm not privy to "horror stories" about browsers/projects gone wrong.

I hope this cleared a few things up.

-Matt

***ElementNode*** - Node with `nodeType == 1`

***HTMLCollection*** - Live array-like NodeList collected by the browser

Comment: +1 This is one of the best, most educational answers I've ever read.

Answer (score 5):

That's a very interesting question. Here are my two cents.

First, it might go without saying, but it depends on *whose* code you're working on. Professional programmers aim to follow company-wide (or, for larger companies, team-wide) best practices, and if DOM Level 0 is discouraged or forbidden by these guidelines, then you should not use it. If it's either allowed or not mentioned at all, then the decision resolves to a personal choice, like for your own code.

Now, there's no obvious technical drawback that prevents you from using Level 0 if you wish to do so. For instance, I would be surprised if iterating over `element.options` was any slower than over `element.getElementsByTagName("option")` or `$("option", element)`. The first syntax is also arguably *more* readable than the alternatives.

Browser support is not a problem either. Level 0 is [older than dirt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model#Legacy_DOM) and has been supported for more than a decade by every script-aware browser under the sun.

However, the above is about *choice*, not *efficiency*, which is what the second half of your question is concerned with. Indeed, you can iterate over `element.options` or `$("option", element)` or `$(element).children("option")` with more or less the same efficiency, but if you have to do heavy work (for instance, wipe out the existing `<option>` elements and add new ones), then using `element.innerHTML` or `$(element).html()` will definitely be faster.

That's because the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3aelement.innerHTML) Level 0 property and the [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) jQuery method (which uses `innerHTML` internally) both delegate all the markup parsing and DOM manipulation to the browser, which is usually written in a lower-level language and  *heavily* optimized for these tasks. Removing the `<option>` elements one by one in a Javascript loop will always be slower in comparison, and in this situation, using DOM Level 0 or all the bells and whistles of jQuery makes absolutely no difference.

Comment: I highly doubt using innerHTML is faster then OOM level 0. Please back that up with benchmarks. Personal benchmarks find that there's no difference between DOM and HTML string manipulation

Comment: @Raynos, `innerHTML` *is* DOM Level 0. Or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: It depends on the scenario but in ie and most browsers innerhtml is generally faster.  http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html

Comment: @Raynos, do you mean your benchmarks show that setting `innerHTML` to the empty string is equivalent in terms of speed to looping over the individual child elements and `remove()`ing them? If so, I am indeed surprised (but that happens :) Can you provide a link?

Comment: @Lime that's out dated information it was true in 2006 Note that the browser tests are IE7 and FF2 that information is just useless today. The difference is gone in recent browsers. [Benchmark](http://jsperf.com/select-options-innerhtml-vs-dom). @FredericHamidi they are the same in chrome. As an aside any non-trivial dom manipulation performs the same with the DOM and innerHTML in modern browsers

Comment: @Raynos, my Firefox 5.0 says `innerhtml 6,012 ±1.92% fastest | dom 2,215 ±0.29% 63% slower`. You're using Chrome, right?

Comment: @FredericHamidi Yes, its slower in FF5. You've also picked the one example where innerHTML wins. In any other non-trivial example there is no difference

Comment: @Raynos, the questioner picked that one example, not me ;)

Comment: Considering ie 6 and ie 7 takes almost 17% market share I definitely wouldn't consider useless.  In fact ie6 and ie7 are often the biggest speed concerns when developing web apps.

Comment: @Lime ... IE6/7 has a market share in china/india/government/enterprise because those areas don't value upgrading. When writing web apps you shouldn't support those _legacy_ browsers unless your specifically targeting one of those 4 areas. I genuinely couldn't care less how slow something runs in IE6/7 as long as it works. If they care about speed they can use a modern browser. IE must die.

Answer (score 3):

*I'll start by saying that I don't know of any "official" statements like "DOM Level 0 considered harmful". This is just my own opinion.*

I think it depends on the case.

The issue I have is that it is problematic, especially with dynamically generated/modified documents, to target specific elements using the collections like `documents.forms` or `documents.images`. Every time I see someone write `document.forms[0]`, I cringe.

Current, and even not-so-current browsers provide the ability via functions like `getElementsByTagName` to simulate the same behaviour, but in a more generic and reusable way. Of course, when you add jQuery into the mix, then there's *no reason at all* to use those collections.

The exceptions I have though, are when you are working in a non-jQuery environment and you're accessing things like `selectElement.options` or `tbodyElement.rows`. In those cases, it really is simpler when you're doing basic stuff like adding or removing items.

Answer (score 3):

> In jQuery-using applications, I've noticed a tendency to, say, change the contents of a drop-down using $(...).html() to switch out the underlying nodes, rather than using element.options[]. Is this because the dom0 collections are best avoided, or because jQuery makes it much easier to change the underlying DOM structure?

That can be explained quite easily. 95% of jQuery developers are ignorant of the fact the DOM API exists or can be used.

The fact that jQuery is abused for things the DOM can do more easily is simply caused by people not learning the DOM.

Personally I'd say use DOM 0, but then again, personally I would say use a DOM shim and don't use jQuery. It's all a matter of choice.

Do whatever is the most ***maintainable***

Comment: I really can't blame someone for not wanting to learn the DOM... can you?

Comment: @nickf the DOM is nowhere near as bad as you think these days. It's no longer the 90s. The DOM3 API is pretty solid. Don't confuse the DOM with the pathetic API IE6-8 exposes.

Comment: Yeah, but you still have to support the older browsers.

Comment: @nickf write a DOM3 shim that makes legacy browsers emulate full standards compliance. Do the same with ES5, CSS3 and HTML5.

Comment: isn't that pretty much what jQuery is?

Comment: @nickf jQuery has an arbitary (and bad) non-standard API. a DOM3 shim has the DOM API. The advantage of a DOM shim is that it's native in modern browsers and therefore faster. The other advantage is that you can get rid of the DOM3 shim in 3 years time when you stop supporting legacy browsers. You can't get rid of jQuery without rewriting your code.

Comment: definitely arbitrary, but why so bad?

Comment: @Jacek_FH [jQuery has a bad API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063874/api-design-and-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

For better or for worse, I use pure DOM level 0 features mainly for debugging. It is sometimes faster to inspect document.forms[0].elements for inputs.

I also use such features when I'm inspecting some page which use some esoteric (or simply unknown to me) framework. I have no time to dig into those abstractions and just inspecting collections directly.

I do believe you'd better know all this DOM zero arsenal, but it's even better if you know about all this modern pure DOM don't-know-which-level-it-is-exaclty level APIs. ClassList collections are nice, for example. I mean, if you are using a framework, you should always know, why do you **exactly** need it.