# Debunking .delay()

Tags: jquery

Please see Matt's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063874/api-design-and-jquery/6064593#6064593). He says that `.delay()` is confusing to most people, and he gives the following example:

`$('#foo').hide().delay(2000).slideDown().text('Hello!').delay(2000).hide();`

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9svb6/) for the fiddle. Could somebody explain the behaviour of that line of code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only certain parts of jQuery's code can be pushed off with `.delay()` -- `hide()` and `text()` are **not** a part of that group.

So basically what the code is doing is (not really doing this, this is just a sketch):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#foo').slideDown();
}, 2000);
$('#foo').hide().text('Hello!').hide();
```

So that is why the `slideDown()` seems to happen last.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it misbehaves has already been explained. To get the desired behaviour, use [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/):

```
$('#foo')
    .hide()
    .delay(2000)
    .slideDown()
    .queue(function() {
        $(this).text('Hello!').dequeue();
    })
    .delay(2000)
    .queue(function() {
        $(this).hide().dequeue();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The `delay` places a delay (no-effect animation) in the animation queue, so it only affect other animations. Chaining `hide` after `delay` doesn't delay the `hide`, it still happens right away.

If you divide the methods into the ones that affect the element at once, and the methods that starts animations, you get this code that does the same:

```
$('#foo').hide().text('Hello!').hide(); // set text and hide twice
$('#foo').delay(2000).slideDown().delay(2000); // wait, slide, wait and do nothing
```